# Can a $3\times3$ matrix have three eigenvalues but only two eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices

I have the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
1.5 & 0 & 1 \\ 
-0.5 & 5 & -0.5 \\ 
-0.5 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$ 
and I found the eigenvalues which are $5$, $1$ and $0.5$

For the eigenvalue $5$, the matrix will be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-3.5 & 0 & 1 \\ 
-0.5 & 0 & -0.5 \\ 
-0.5 & 0 & -5  \end{bmatrix}.$$
From the second and the third row (if we transfor them into equations) you can see that the $x_1$ equals to two different values.
Does that make the matrix $A$ for eigenvalue $5$ to have no eigenvectors?

Comment: The equations you get will reduce to $x_1=-x_3$ and $x_1=-10x_3,$ which require that $x_3=10x_3,$ that is, $x_3=0.$ So, $x_1=0$ as well. Since $x_2$ does not appear in any equation, its value is arbitrary. So, your eigenvectors will be scalar multiples of the vector $(0,1,0),$ as pointed out below by gimusi.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, since you have found three distinct eigenvalues, at each one corresponds exactly an eigenspace with dimension one, that is we have infinitely many eigenvectors associated to each eigenvalue but they are all in the form $k\cdot \vec v_1$ with $k\neq 0$.

In that case we have that $\vec v_1=(0,1,0)$.